# Organising code that includes php and javascript files

Tags: php, javascript

I have a website where I am including a php library file and a javascript library file.  I have condensed the problem to the following files:

**index.php**

```
<?php
  include('constants.php');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:show_const_1('<?php echo(CONST_TEXT); ?>');
                           show_const_2();">
    Some text here
  </body>
</html>
```

**constants.php**

```
<?php
  define('CONST_TEXT', 'Hello World');
?>
```

**lib.js**

```
function show_const_1(string)
{
  alert(string);
}

function show_const_2()
{
  alert('<?php echo(CONST_TEXT); ?>');
}
```

The result is that when the page loads I get two message boxes.  The first says "Hello World" and the second says "<?php echo(CONST_TEXT); ?>".  The first javascript method does what I want it to, but I will be using the function in many places across the site and so ideally I don't want to have to pass the constant as a parameter every time.

Is there a good way to rearrange the code to make the second javascript method work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is rename "lib.js" to "lib.php".

You should also add

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
```

to the top of the file.

Incidentally, you should us [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to output text to javascript:

```
alert(<?php echo json_encode(CONST_TEXT); ?>);
```

And "javascript:" doesn't belong in event attributes (which are kindof outdated anyway):

```
<body onload="doSomething();">
```

Comment: The MIME type of JavaScript is now *application/javascript*.

Comment: Lots of helpful comments - thanks.  Php is now being executed in lib.php, but the constant CONST_TEXT does not appear to be defined in lib.php.

The php <?php echo CONST_TEXT; ?> results in the string "CONST_TEXT" (as opposed to "Hello World").

Comment: You probably need to include() whichever file you define CONST_TEXT in

Answer (score 2):

The method body inside `alert()` is not interpreted by PHP (it's interpreted by Javascript), so you can't put PHP tag in it

Comment: The following works fine in a php file:
    alert('<?php echo 123; ?>');